# Spring security oauth2 client token getting mixed up when there are lots of concurrent users

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-webclient

We are using spring boot 2.7.18 with spring security oauth2 client to make request to an api endpoint. We use the oauth2 password grant type. Here is the oauth2 client configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class MyAppOauth2ClientConfiguration {
    
    @Bean
    ClientRegistration myAppClientRegistration(
            @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.myapp.token-uri}") String token_uri,
            @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.myapp.client-id}") String client_id,
            @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.myapp.client-secret}") String client_secret,
            @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.myapp.scope}") String scope,
            @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.myapp.authorization-grant-type}") String authorizationGrantType
    ) {
        return ClientRegistration
                .withRegistrationId("myapp")
                .tokenUri(token_uri)
                .clientId(client_id)
                .clientSecret(client_secret)
                .scope(scope.split(","))
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.PASSWORD)
                .build();
    }

    
    @Bean
    public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository(
            ClientRegistration myappClientRegistration) {
        return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(myappClientRegistration);
    }

    // Create the authorized client service
    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientService oauth2AuthorizedClientService(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        return new InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrationRepository);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository() {
        return new HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository();
    }

    // Create the authorized client manager and service manager using the
    // beans created and configured above
    @Bean
    public DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager (
            ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {

        OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
                OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                        .password()
                        .build();
        
        DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
                new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                        clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository);
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);
        
        return authorizedClientManager;
    }
    
}
```

We then create webclient to make the api call:

```
private WebClient createWebClient(String userLoginName, String userPassword, String clientRegistrationId) {

        Map<String, Object> passwordAttributes = new HashMap<>();

        passwordAttributes.put(OAuth2AuthorizationContext.USERNAME_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, userLoginName);
        passwordAttributes.put(OAuth2AuthorizationContext.PASSWORD_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, userPassword);

        authorizedClientManager.setContextAttributesMapper(request -> passwordAttributes);

        ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2 = new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
                authorizedClientManager);
        oauth2.setDefaultClientRegistrationId(clientRegistrationId);

        final int size = 16 * 1024 * 1024;
        final ExchangeStrategies strategies = ExchangeStrategies.builder()
                .codecs(codecs -> codecs.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(size)).build();

        final Builder builder = WebClient.builder().filter(errorHandler()).exchangeStrategies(strategies)
                .baseUrl(apiBaseUrl).defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).filter(oauth2);
        
        return builder.build();

    }
```

When there are lots of concurrent users it seems like the oauth tokens are getting mixed up one user is using another user's token

Comment: *When there are lots of concurrent users it seems like the oauth tokens are getting mixed up one user is using another user's token* How do you know?

Comment: User were complaining they were see view that is not correct seems to belong to someone else. So we added a api call to get back user principal associate with token and we see the user and token are mismatched

Comment: Anyone has any ideas on this still stuck on this issue

Comment: You need to provide logs, to see what happens.